# how to adjust Google Sheets cell formula for financial stock market reporting

Tags: google-sheets

There is a financial stock portfolio tracking spreadsheet available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14VdN6NctxcpDshQ9Ndzbt9IM4n4DQQaU7LWHS8Gnka4/edit#gid=1138434302).

What I found was that this spreadsheet is not counting Dividend transactions towards the Units count on the `Stock Summary` page, which skews the `Summary` page, undervaluing your portfolio.

I think to make the spreadsheet more accurate, I need to adjust the `Cumulative Units` (column J) cell formulas on the `Transactions` sheet ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14VdN6NctxcpDshQ9Ndzbt9IM4n4DQQaU7LWHS8Gnka4/edit#gid=334471658)) to also count units received as Dividends. The cells in column J have formula:

(Cell J2):

```
=if(B2="Buy",I2+D2,if(B2="Sell",I2-D2,if(B2="Div",I2,if(B2="Split",I2*G2,if(B2="CapReduct",I2,0)))))
```

I've tested this formula, and the cumulative units count does not update when the transaction is a `Div`.

How do I adjust the 2nd formula above to count both `Buy` & `Div` transactions?

Thanks in advance. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be for you to add a new column (You can hide it) and test

```
if B2 is Buy or Div 
=OR(B2="Buy",B2="Div")
```

This function will return TRUE or FALSE.

Now you amend your original formula to read this new column (rather than B2, let's say you are doing this calculation on K2)  for TRUE, rather than Buy.

Try this then:

`=IF(K2=TRUE,I2+D2,IF(B2="Sell",I2-D2,IF(B2="Div",I2,IF(B2="Split",I2*G2,IF(B2="CapReduct",I2,0)))))`

Sorry in simple steps, in case it's confusing:

1. If you can free-up row K2 and add this formula:
   `=OR(B2="Buy",B2="Div")`
2. Change your original formula (that you
   posted) to this:

   =IF(K2=TRUE,I2+D2,IF(B2="Sell",I2-D2,IF(B2="Div",I2,IF(B2="Split",I2*G2,IF(B2="CapReduct",I2,0)))))

Comment: That's great Caroline, thank you. Is there any way we can integrate the two cell formulas together to remove the requirement for an extra column? The extra column breaks a lot of other calculations.

Comment: I moved the extra column to the end of the other columns, and adjusted the formula in the `cumulative units` cell to reference the last column, so the spreadsheet is no longer broken, but removing the extra column would be helpful. :-)